# How to convert a JPEG image into SVG format using ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick

How to convert a JPEG image into SVG format using ImageMagick?

Answer (score 64):

you'll need to use [potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/) and convert to a bitmap first.

```
$convert input.jpg output.ppm
$potrace -s output.ppm -o svgout.svg
```

Comment: Great tool. Thanks for this tip.

Comment: as a one-liner without intermediate file I used: `convert -channel RGB -compress None input.jpg bmp:- | potrace -s - -o output.svg`

Comment: Apart from Portable PixMap `.ppm`, Portable GrayMap `.pgm` and even Portable Bitmap `.pbm` can also be used as intermediate file type. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) is more information.

Comment: This seems to answer the question and should be selected as the most appropriate answer yet.

Comment: Portrace does not support more than 2 colors :(

Answer (score 35):

Actually, with a complete installation of a recent version of ImageMagick it should be as easy as:

```
convert  some.jpeg  some.svg
```

Of course, ImageMagick cannot do it all by itself -- it uses *delegates* (helper programs) to handle SVG input or output. (This has been pointed out by other answers already.)

To see a (partial) list of all delegates (and their respective commands), run

```
convert  -list delegate
```

To see the config file where all the delegate secrets hide, see

```
convert  -list delegate | grep delegates.xml
```

To see a (partial) list of SVG handling delegates, run

```
convert  -list delegate | grep -i svg
```

However, ImageMagick likes to put some of its external helper utilities into 'stealth' mode and doesn't necessarily reveal their presence when using above commands.

Just look into the `delegates.xml` file itself. On my system it's:

```
grep -i svg /opt/local/etc/ImageMagick/delegates.xml | grep -i --color stealth

  <delegate decode="autotrace" stealth="True" \
            command="&quot;/opt/local/bin/convert&quot; &quot;%i&quot; \
            &quot;pnm:%u&quot;\n\
            &quot;/opt/local/bin/autotrace&quot; \
           -input-format pnm \
           -output-format svg \
           -output-file &quot;%o&quot; &quot;%u&quot;"/>

  <delegate decode="svg:decode" stealth="True" \
            command="&quot;/opt/local/bin/inkscape&quot; &quot;%s&quot; \
            --export-png=&quot;%s&quot; \
            --export-dpi=&quot;%s&quot; \
            --export-background=&quot;%s&quot; \
            --export-background-opacity=&quot;%s&quot; \
            &gt; &quot;%s&quot; 2&gt;&amp;1"/>
```

As you may see, on *my* system the ImageMagick installation automatically uses (amongst others)...

- ...`inkscape` to convert SVG to PNG;
- ...`autotrace` to convert PNM to SVG;

Of course, one could argue the benefits of rather using `autotrace` directly -- but that would require to manually convert the whatever-input-format to PNM first. So for this preliminary step you'd probably use ImageMagick anyway...

Comment: When I tried this and opened the svg it simply embeded the png data into the svg xml.

Comment: @Clintm This is fully expected. ImageMagick does't vectorize

Answer (score 18):

You'll actually need some software or code to vectorize your image in between, as jpg is a raster format, while SVG is a vector format. I don't think imagemagick alone can do that for you.

Comment: +1: Turning a bunch of lines into a large matrix of pixels can be done fairly dumbly. Doing the reverse requires some fairly serious smarts.