# Clipping or Masking the Images in Automated way

Tags: javascript, css, clip-path

There are online tools like [clippy](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) or [css plant](http://www.cssplant.com/clip-path-generator) which will create clip path as in [code pen](https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/OdozOG) for **different shaped** imges manually, But we have **thousands of images**, so its not possible to create clip path for each images **manually**....

So is there any way we can automate this clipping process ? or is there any other way [ like **masking** , svg ,inkspace ] ? I need some **generic** solution....

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(42% 100%,  %, 81% 71%, 88% 60%, 95% 50%, 99% 40%, 100% 36%,);
```

Comment: basically i have thousands of json file like these  : https://pastebin.com/ah9NRGzj - each json file contains image path, so i need to do clip for each images....

Comment: This is offtopic for stackoverflow. There is no easy way to do it. But you might find some tools to help you.

Comment: Check [Imagemagick discussion (see the inner links)](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=23890), [How to convert a JPEG image into SVG format using ImageMagick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132601/how-to-convert-a-jpeg-image-into-svg-format-using-imagemagick) , 
[potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/), 
[how-do-i-convert-a-png-to-svg-using-software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470495/how-do-i-convert-a-png-to-svg-using-software) and
[Inkscape: tracing pixel art](https://inkscape.org/doc/tutorials/tracing-pixelart/tutorial-tracing-pixelart.html)

Comment: Thanks for links, someone suggested this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54548573/dragging-one-image-makes-other-image-to-drag/54607448?noredirect=1#comment96209705_54607448 is that possible ?